# make: *** No targets. Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is what I have for creating *.o files, I do not want to create dinary file. This GNUmake sits in /obj. Needless to say, it is not working. Do you happen to know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You've asked essentially the same question three times now. Please try to understand the answers and put them to work, don't just dump your latest makefile here every time you hit a snag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
all: $(OBJS)

%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -I$(INC_DIR) -c $< -o $@
```